# Space after the title of the table of content

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I want to ask if there is a way to add a space after the title of the table of content (Like the space indicated by the red arrow) without affecting the space of other section's headers?!

Class type:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

The code used to print the table of content:

```
\tableofcontents{}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably yes. Depends on the class you are using and if an toc-changing packages are loaded/used. In other words: Can you provide a miial working example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use eg

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{5cm}}
```

right after `\tableofcontents` to add `5cm` vertical space below the ToC header.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{5cm}}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```